# How to make Yii2 model as array?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I am creating a set of data using krajee widget. 
I want to add some buttons to append/delete a group of data, but the question is how to make an array model, and how to get all these data in post function in my controllers ?

My widget like that:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'name')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $list,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => '-Select-'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
])->label(false);
```

I want to append this in JavaScript and got the array data like :

`[0]=>peter,[1]=>jim` ...

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Show your `$list` variable value. by printing `print_r($list);`

Answer (score 0):

According [Documentation](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) of Select2 Widget, you must use:

```
'options' => [
    'placeholder' => '-Select-',
    'multiple' => true
],
```